# How do I import google.com/bookmarks into Google docs Chrome folder?

Tags: google-drive, import, google-bookmarks

Note: this is not a Chrome question, it's a Google docs question.

How do I import my google.com/bookmarks into the docs folder that is used by Chrome to sync bookmarks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method would be to [export your bookmarks from Google Bookmarks](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/export-your-google-bookmarks.html).  This will generate a bookmarks.html file that can be [imported into Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96816) via the Bookmark Manager.  Then if you [enable bookmark syncing in Chrome](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139), it should move your bookmarks to the Google Docs Chrome folder.  It's a round-about method, but should work.